# not matched by vs. unmatched by

Tags: comparisons

I want to use two sentences as examples for my questions:

i) The amount of A will not be matched by that of B.

ii) The amount of A will be unmatched by that of B.

Is it correct to say that: ii) only suggests that B's amount will be greater; whereas i) shows at least two possibilities---either B's will be greater or A will be greater?

I am not sure but it seems to me that "not matched by" suggests a difference, unlike "unmatched" which shows one is greater than the other.

Could anyone help explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the many meanings  of  *match*, two are relevant: one of equality and one of implied comparison.

> a match =
>
> *a person or thing that is equal to another person or thing in strength, speed, or quality*:
>
> "We are matched in strength"
>
> *to be less powerful or effective than someone or something else*:
>
> "Gibson ran well but was no match for the young Italian."
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/match)

Therefore, either of your statements may be understood simply to say that A and B are not equal, without making any comparison.

And either may be understood to imply that A and B are unequal. Which is the bigger may only be understood from context and not by the order in which A and B appear in the sentence. Consider:

"The beans in a jug are *unmatched*/*not matched* by the beans in a silo."

"The beans in a silo are *unmatched*/*not matched* by the beans in a jug."

The order of A and B is irrelevant; we understand from each statement that a silo holds much more than a jug.